# If Graham's number used $4$s instead of $3$s, at which $G$ would that number be bigger than Graham's number?

Tags: big-numbers, hyperoperation

If  $3\uparrow \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=G_1$, $ \quad G_2=\underbrace{3 \uparrow \ldots\uparrow3}_{G_1 \ \text{times}}, \quad G_3=\underbrace{3 \uparrow \ldots\uparrow3}_{G_2 \ \text{times}}$ , $ \quad\ldots \ , \quad G_n=\underbrace{3 \uparrow \ldots\uparrow3}_{G_{n-1} \ \text{times}}$ etc. until  $G_{64}$

(where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\quad \uparrow \quad$ is [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation)).

At which G would this number be bigger, if it  had started with $4\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 4$ as $G_1$?.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Are you a logician by any chance?

Comment: @Pedro: Spooky! You answered Alessandro's question before he asked it.

Comment: Bigger than what?

Comment: $G_{63}$ would still be smaller than Graham's number.

Answer (score 2):

Let the Graham's number sequence be $G_1=3\uparrow^43$ and $G_{k+1}=3\uparrow^{G_k}3$ for $k\ge 1$. Now define the new sequence $A_1=4\uparrow^44$ and $A_{k+1}=4\uparrow^{A_k}4$ for $k\ge 1$. Then $A_k<G_{k+1}<A_{k+1}$ for all $k\ge 1$. In particular, $A_{63}<G_{64}<A_{64}$.

Proof (by induction): We show that $G_{k+1}>A_k+1$ for all $k\ge 1$.

1. Base case: $G_2>A_1+1$
   $$\begin{align}G_2 &= 3\uparrow^{G_1}3=3\uparrow^{G_1-1}(3\uparrow^{G_1-1}3)\\
   &>(3\uparrow^{G_1-1}2)\uparrow^{G_1-1}(3\uparrow^{G_1-1}3-2)\\
   &>4\uparrow^{4}4+1=A_1+1
   \end{align}$$ 
   where the first inequality follows from Saibian's theorem$^\dagger$, and the second inequality follows from $G_1=3\uparrow^43$.
2. Induction: $G_{k}>A_{k-1}+1\implies G_{k+1}>A_{k}+1$
   $$\begin{align}G_{k+1} &= 3\uparrow^{G_k}3=3\uparrow^{G_k-1}(3\uparrow^{G_k-1}3)\\
   &>(3\uparrow^{G_k-1}2)\uparrow^{G_k-1}(3\uparrow^{G_k-1}3-2)\\
   &>4\uparrow^{A_{k-1}}4+1=A_k+1
   \end{align}$$ 
   where again the first inequality follows from Saibian's theorem, and the second inequality follows from the induction hypothesis.

$\dagger$ [Saibian's theorem](http://vixra.org/pdf/1405.0284v1.pdf): For any integers $b\ge 2,\,k\ge 2,\,m\ge 1,\,n\ge 1,$ $$(b\uparrow^k m)\uparrow^k n \ < \ b\uparrow^k (m+n).$$